# Use findViewById in the FragmentActivity to get Id in Fragment (multi fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, findviewbyid

I have the following code that is a FragmentActivity with 5 fragments:

```
public class Mm_Registration_ConfigSettings extends FragmentActivity
{

private ViewPager viewPager;
private FragmentPagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_configsettings);

    adapter    =   new FragmentPagerAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager() )
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public Fragment getItem( final int index)
                                        {
                                            switch (index)
                                            {
                                                case 0:
                                                    return new Mm_Registration_ConfigSettings_fragment1();
                                                case 1:
                                                    return new Mm_Registration_ConfigSettings_fragment2();
                                                case 2:
                                                    return new Mm_Registration_ConfigSettings_fragment3();
                                                case 3:
                                                    return new Mm_Registration_ConfigSettings_fragment4();
                                                case 4:
                                                    return new Mm_Registration_ConfigSettings_fragment5();
                                            }

                                            return null;
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public int getCount() {
                                            // get item count - equal to number of tabs
                                            return 5;
                                        }

                                    };

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout ) findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager( (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager), true);

}

public void nextFragment( View v )
{
    if ( viewPager.getCurrentItem() < 4 )
        viewPager.setCurrentItem( viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true );
    else
    {
        if ( !( (CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.licenseAccept ) ).isChecked() )
            Toast.makeText( Mm_Registration_ConfigSettings.this, "Accept the license to continue." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        else
        {
            HashMap hashMap     =   new HashMap();

            hashMap.put( "switch_sex" , ( ( ( (Switch) findViewById( R.id.switch_sex ) ).isChecked() ) ? 1 : 0 ) );
            hashMap.put( "switch_smoker" , ( ( ( (Switch) findViewById( R.id.switch_smoker ) ).isChecked() ) ? 1 : 0 ) );
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

}

In some Fragment there are few EditText and other widgets.
In the last Fragment, the button associated with `nextFragment` try to get the data the user inserted in the previous `Fragments` without success.

Anyone can help me to figure out how to get those data?
Thank you

Comment: So you have a finish button in the last fragment and you are looking to get data from the other fragments?

Comment: dazza5000, yes I am. You got the point